# Argument of type A is not assignable to parameter of type B

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, swagger-codegen

I try to make a call to my back-end with angular.
I have already method get/delete works.

But I have an issue with "POST".

I use swaggercode-gen to generate all my classes in TS.

But when I mak the call to my create function, I have this message : "Message Argument of type Employee is not assignable to parameter of type event"

Employee is my own class.

I try a lot of thing, I try to change my form, I try to change typescript file (it is indicate to not to).

Swagger-codegen generate for me employee.ts file, this file is OK.

It generates also an employee.service.ts file, with my create function :

employe.service.ts :

```
public createEmployee(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<any>;
public createEmployee(observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>;
public createEmployee(observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
public createEmployee(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    // to determine the Accept header
    let httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
    ];
    const httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected != undefined) {
        headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }

    // to determine the Content-Type header
    const consumes: string[] = [
        'application/json'
    ];

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.basePath}/employees/createEmployee`,
        null,
        {
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
}
```

My form:

employee-form.component.html :

```
   <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="create()">
    <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Matricule</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idEmployee" [(ngModel)]="employee.idEmployee" name="idEmployee"/>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nom</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" [(ngModel)]="employee.lastName"  name="lastName"/>
      </div>
    </div>.

   [...]

   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Créer</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Retour</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

My type script file :

employee-form.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'adv-employee-form',
  templateUrl: './employee-form.component.html',
  providers: [EmployeeService],
  styles: []
})
export class EmployeeFormComponent implements OnInit {

  employee: Employee;

  constructor(private router: Router, private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   create() {
     this.employeeService.createEmployee(this.employee)//<- The error appear here
       .pipe(finalize(() => this.router.navigate(['/employees-list']))).subscribe();
   }
}
```

It seems this.employee is not recognize correctly.

I try to change employee-form.component.ts and set :
`employee: any = Employee;`

The error disappear. But When I post my form, I have error :

`ERROR Error: Unreachable: unhandled observe type [object Object]}`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, your method doesn't expect parameter of type employee also you are passing in body I think you need to post employee object so create employee method in the service should be

```
public createEmployee(model:any,observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    // to determine the Accept header
    let httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
    ];
    const httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected != undefined) {
        headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }

    // to determine the Content-Type header
    const consumes: string[] = [
        'application/json'
    ];

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.basePath}/employees/createEmployee`,
        model,
        {
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
}
```